Pull Chances for Sovereign Rico?
What is the chance of getting any of the new Rico skins (regular, gem, and bling) from the Mega Boxes? Do you have a higher chance of getting the new Rico skins by "stacking up" boxes to open them together?

A Mega Box is ten rolls with the following chances as published on their support page (archive.org Archive).



Drop
Drop Chance




Coins
19.10%


XP Doublers
19.10%


Power Points
18.91%


Bling
18.82%


Gems
9.45%


Classic Pin
4.682%


Classic Profile Icon
4.682%


Rare skin
1.873%


Super Rare skin
1.873%


Epic Brawler
1.873%


Epic skin
0.468%


Hypercharge skin
0.281%


Mythic Brawler
0.187%


Legendary Brawler
0.094%



*Note: This list condenses the list of individual drops into their categories. For example, coins has three denomination with a common, uncommon and rare chance.
And the chance of getting it is 0.281% (three variants × 0.094%).
Since each roll is independent of each other, it would be a skin every 1 in 356 rolls (36 mega boxes since you can't buy 0.6 of one).
You are also guaranteed the base variant after buying (or opening?) 10 mega boxes.


Do you have a higher chance of getting the new Rico skins by "stacking up" boxes to open them together?

If you mean a chance to get it in one of the many pulls, from that perspective, yes. More rolls mean more chances at getting it.
But if you look at each box individually as a single moment each (and the correct mathematical way to look at it), no as if you add up everybody's pulls it'll trend towards that 1 in 36 boxes as intended in the long run, even if some have lucky and unlucky streaks.

You can also find their pre-removal chances here.



Drop
Drop Chance




Power Points + Coins
~ 92.05%


Rare Brawler1
~ 2.77%


Super Rare Brawler1
~ 1.25%


Epic Brawler1
~ 0.56%


Mythic Brawler1
~ 0.26%


Legendary Brawler1
~ 0.11%


Star Power2
~ 1.00%


Gadget2
~ 2.00%



1 every draw that didn't award a brawler would increase a "luck" value which would decrease the chance of getting power points and coins and getting a brawler instead.
2 fixed chance as long as you have star powers or gadgets that are possible to get, otherwise it gets rerolled.
